# How do I properly convert an array of type real(kind=8) to one of type real(kind=4) in Fortran

Tags: types, casting, fortran, gfortran

This question applies to Fortran, more precisely the compiler gfortran.

I need to know how I can convert a real(kind=8) array to a real(kind=4) array such that all reasonable digits in each entry of the array remain.

Obviously, a type cast from kind=8 to kind=4 implies a loss of information. Hence, what I am looking for is the proper way to lose just as much information as necessary - but not more.

Comment: Can you give examples to show why you think gfortran (or any compiler) is throwing away more information than necessary when changing kind parameter?

Comment: Your comment made me think, francescalus. I think there is no reason to believe that more information than necessary is lost, when one casts real(kind=8) to real(kind=4) variables.

Comment: My problem is different from what I thought, see below.

Answer (score 6):

The conversion to real is done using the `real()` intrinsic function. The optional `kind=` argument specifies the kind of the result.

If you truly need the result to be kind 4, you use

```
 real(x, 4)
```

and you can do whatever you want with the result. For example, assign it to a variable.

You will get the same result with an implicit conversion, but the explicit conversion shows the intent and also avoids certain compiler warnings about a possible loss of precision.

As always:

1. It is better to use named constants for your kind parameters so that you can change it everywhere easily.
2. Using kind numbers as literal constants like 4 or 8 is not portable and is really ugly. [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter)

Comment: clarification to the last point:  a simple assignment would also do the trick. Assume `x` is of type `REAL` and `y` is of type `DOUBLE PRECISION`, you can just do `x=y`. the conversion is done implicitly (however, this hides the conversion, and writing things out makes the intent of the code readable). You can also write `x=real(y,kind(x))`

Comment: Dear Vladimir F and kvantour. Thank you for your explanations, these made me smarter. As a result, I now do all type conversions explicitly, in order to convey my intent. I do indeed need real(kind=4) variables in order to get an old plotting library work (PGPLOT). My first thought was that the type conversion must be wrong. Instead, I am using FFTPACK5.1, which does not adapt properly to the -fdefault-real-8 compiler option, because all kind declarations are explicit in FFTPACK5.1. The erroneous behaviour of my code stems from the fact that I falsely assumed FFTPACK5.1 to adapt generically...

Comment: ...to the -fdefault-real-8 compiler option.